# test2.rb:15:in `<main>': undefined method `exists?' for "skilleddev":String (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

Someone please help me with this error! Any help is appreciated!

```
username = "skilleddev"

if username.exists?
    puts "Variable 'username' exists."
else
    puts "Variable 'username' does not exist."
end
```

Comment: What's the issue here? error message is self explanatory.

Comment: The error message is quite descriptive in this case, the problem is exactly what it says.

Comment: I think you need `blank?` instead of  `exists?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is raised, because a `String` object doesn't have `exists?` method. If you want to check whether a variable is defined, then you should use `defined?` method:

```
username = "skilleddev"

if defined?(username)
    puts "Variable 'username' exists."
else
    puts "Variable 'username' does not exist."
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Or if you want to know if the variable is a string:

```
username = "skilleddev"

if username.instance_of? String
    puts "Variable 'username' exists as String.."
else
    puts "Variable 'username' does not exist as String."
end
```